# file exists but fopen "failed to open stream no such file or directory"

Tags: php, fopen

It's a really strange problem.

```
$file = '/home/wwwroot/website/web/modules/homegrid/css/bootstrap-carousel.min.css';
clearstatcache();
var_dump(file_exists($file));//output true
var_dump(is_file($file));//output true
var_dump(is_dir($file));//output false
var_dump(is_readable($file));//output true
var_dump(is_writable($file));//output true
var_dump(fopen($file, 'w+'));//output false
var_dump(file_put_contents($file, 'asdfasdf'));//output false
```

fopen and file_put_contents always false, but file exists.
In php 5.6 and php-fpm

Comment: is it a symobl link?

Comment: not a link, permission is -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: `(fopen($file, 'r+'));` try this

Comment: Can you edit the question withthe result of `ls -larth /home/wwwroot/website/web/modules/homegrid/css/bootstrap-carousel.min.css`. It will display some usefull information about the file.

Comment: sorry, it's still fopen(/home/wwwroot/website/web/modules/homegrid/css/bootstrap-carousel.min.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: use  r+ like this `(fopen($file, 'r+'));`

Comment: ls -larth result:-rwxrwxrwx 1 www www 0 Jul  6 18:18

Comment: r+ result: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 8 hours finally I find out the solution, but still don't know why.

```
if(file_exists($file))
{
    unlink($file);
    touch($file);
}
var_dump(fopen($file, 'w+'));//output resource
```

it's just like something block the file writing, I never heard php has any file blocking thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try to check the last error

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'w+');
if ( !$fp ) {
  echo 'last error: ';
  var_dump(error_get_last());
}
else {
  echo "ok.\n";
}
```

Comment: You also can use the `fopen($file, 'w+') or die(error_get_last());` notation for killing the script here and display the error.

Comment: error_get_last return a error not related to this problem: "ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete"

Comment: @znjack look for few previous errors. Mulitple errors can be thrown by the same function

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen($file, "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $txt = "asdfasdf";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);

    fclose($myfile);
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```

change `(fopen($file, 'w+'));` to this `(fopen($file, 'r+'));`.

File Permissions

1. r+  **Open a file for read/write.** File pointer starts at the
   beginning of the file
2. w+  **Open a file for read/write.** Erases the contents of the file
   or creates a new file if it doesn't exist. File pointer starts at
   the beginning of the file

Comment: I tried r+, it's still "failed to open stream: No such file or directory ", it looks like folder not exists, but file_exists and other function return true.